# alternative way of passing argument to parent class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

hello what's the alternative way of passing arguments to the parent class other than passing the arguments using the super() method like the following

```
class food () {
   constructor (name) {
      this. name = name;
   }
}

class junkfood extends food {
   constructor () {
      super();
      // no args
      this.type = "bad"
   }
}

var breakfast = new junkfood('pizza')
```

currently am using the following

```
class food () {
   constructor (name) {
      this. name = name;
   }
}

class junkfood extends food {
   constructor (name) {
      super(name);
      this.type = "bad"
   }
}

var breakfast = new junkfood('pizza')
```

as seen above I don't want junk food to associate with food name argument

Comment: my objective is to cutt off repeating the args why does one thing have to do with the other

Comment: So, if you don't need `junkfood` to have a `name`, it seems your design is incorrect. A child constructor can take more or less arguments than the parent but *in most cases*, it still calls the parent constructor supplying any argument the parent needs, even if it doesn't take them, e.g, if you have `A` that takes `id, type`, then `B extends A` the child constructor might automatically pass `"myType"` as the `type` for the parent. It might even generate the `id` automatically and the only arguments it takes are `description` which the parent doesn't know or care about.

Comment: Why do you want an "alternative"? It's not clear to me what the question is here

Comment: Probably what you are looking for in design is an "abstract class". But really I do not recommend you learn OOP with Javascript. Look for a base in any strict language such Java or C#

Comment: @Liam @VLAZ @SAM `class parent { constructor (name) { this.name = name; customconstructor(); }} class child extends parent { customconstructor {console. log(this.name)}}; let me = new child ('John'); // returns 'John'`